# Why does when i insert the value needed in postman error

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-firestore

The function:

```
def get_ticket_type(db: firestore.Client, logger: logging.RootLogger, umum:int, anggota:int, pelajar:int, tiket_teater:int, jumlah_tiket:int):
    result: dict = {
        "is_get_data": False,
        "is_function_error": False,
    }
    try:
        if umum == 1:
            if tiket_teater == 1:
                id = 4
            else:
                id = 1
        elif anggota == 1:
            if jumlah_tiket >= 3:
                tiket_teater = 1
                id = 6
            elif jumlah_tiket < 3:
                tiket_teater = 1
                id = 5
        elif pelajar == 1:
            if jumlah_tiket >= 40:
                tiket_teater = 1
                id = 8
            elif jumlah_tiket < 40:
                tiket_teater = 1
                id = 7
        doc = db.collection("ticket").document(id).get()
        if doc.exists:
            print("Document ada")
            
            doc_data = doc.to_dict()
            print(f"doc_data = {doc_data}")
            print()

            result["is_get_data"] = True

            data: dict = {
                "id": doc_data["id"],
                "Nama Tiket": doc_data["nama_tiket"],
                "Nama Akses": doc_data["nama_akses"],
                "Harga Tiket": doc_data["harga_tiket"]
            }
            result["data"] = data
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        result["is_function_error"] = True
        result["error_message"] = str(e)

    return result
```

When i try putting the value needed in postman it showed this error message: local variable 'id' referenced before assignment. When i put id = None then this error message show up: missing 1 required positional argument: 'str'. I dont know why because my function doesnt even have str in the argument

I tried setting the variable as id = None, i tried searching my function even though i dont call any str in my function

Comment: You don't set `id` if none of the `if` conditions are true. Add an `else:` block to report this error or use a default value for the rest of the function.

Comment: General advice: When your `elif` condition is the exact opposite of the `if` condition, use `else:` instead.

Comment: The missing argument is happening in something you call. `db.collection("ticket").document(None)` is probably not a valid argument.

Comment: Post the full traceback of the error. Put it in a code block so formatting will be retained.